# Reset Safari as if never run

Tags: safari

How can I reset Safari as if it was never run, so that it opens with a "Welcome to Safari" window?

I've tried removing all traces of Safari in ~/Library without luck.
I am just curious where this information is stored.

I'm running El Capitan 10.11.6.

[image]

Comment: [This site](https://macpaw.com/how-to/reset-safari-on-mac) may help. I don't want to run through it to verify because ... I don't want to reset Safari!

Comment: @IconDaemon That tutorial makes no attempt to reset *any* Safari settings, let alone whatever one controls the Welcome page :(

Comment: If you deleted Safari and don't have a Time Machine backup or other backup, reinstall macOS to put Safari back in your Applications folder. Reinstalling macOS doesn't remove data from your computer. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204416 So fresh install is one way to do it.

Comment: @ankii, my question is not about that

Comment: The article states: "The result is that Safari is clean and should behave as if you’ve just installed it. " True - it doesn't reduce Safari to a 'never been run before' state, but it comes darned close. This may be as close as you can get to that state.

Answer (score 2):

Did you also go through the subfolders within ~/Library? Safari files are in a number of different places within that folder?

A view examples:

Caches contains com.apple.Safari and com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing

Containers has multiple com.apple.Safari folders (may not exist on 10.11.6, I don't have anything with that OS to compare to)

Preferences, etc.

Comment: Yes, I’ve removed everything containing Safari or safari in their name. No luck.